# Create a transaction around the generated sql inserts with Sql Management Objects

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, transactions, smo

I use sql server 2012 with SMO and c#.

With this method I generate insert statements from the data inside the table and save this insert statements in the MySqlInsertDataStatements.sql file.

What I want to do now is to wrap **all** the insert statements from all tables with a transaction and rollback behavior.

How do I have to change my code that I can do this feature **with the help of the SMO library**.

```
public static void ScriptData(string filePath, Database db, Scripter scripter)
        {         
            scripter.Options.ScriptData = true;
            scripter.Options.ScriptSchema = false;
            scripter.Options.WithDependencies = false;
            scripter.Options.IncludeHeaders = false;
            foreach (Table tbl in db.Tables.Cast<Table>().Where(t => !t.IsSystemObject))
            {               
                scripter.Options.FileName = filePath + @"\MySqlInsertDataStatements.sql";
                tbl.EnumScript(scripter.Options);              
            }
        }
```

This is a sample output how the MySqlInsertDataStatements.sql content looks like:

```
Use MyDatabase


Insert 1 Table1
Insert 2 Table1

Go


Insert 1 Table2
Insert 2 Table2

Go
```

Answer (score 0):

The ServerConnection reference that you should have in order to have gotten access to a Database has methods BeginTransaction, CommitTransaction and RollBackTransaction - you should be able to use these to achieve what you are trying to do.

Here is a complete example of how they may be used:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var serverConnection = new ServerConnection(serverInstance: ".");
    var server = new Server(new ServerConnection());
    var scripter = new Scripter(server) { Options = { ScriptData = true } };

    serverConnection.BeginTransaction();
    ScriptData(".", server.Databases["NORTHWND"], scripter);
    serverConnection.RollBackTransaction();
}

public static void ScriptData(string filePath, Database db, Scripter scripter)
{
    scripter.Options.ScriptData = true;
    scripter.Options.ScriptSchema = false;
    scripter.Options.WithDependencies = false;
    scripter.Options.IncludeHeaders = false;
    foreach (Table tbl in db.Tables.Cast<Table>().Where(t => !t.IsSystemObject))
    {
        scripter.Options.FileName = filePath + @"\MySqlInsertDataStatements.sql";
        tbl.EnumScript(scripter.Options);
    }
}
```

Comment: You misunderstood me. I do not want to wrap the creation of the script inside a transaction. I want create a transaction before my string insert statements and close the it with the rollback string.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I see. From what I understand of SMO scripting capabilities, it would not be possible to do this in the general case since there are some actions which may not be wrapped in a transaction (such as CREATE DATABASE). However, for the sorts of action that you have shown here, a transaction should be fine - you could either execute the script using a SqlConnection with a transaction (as in my initial code) or.. and this does, admittedly, sound very ugly.. inject BEGIN TRAN and ROLLBACK TRAN lines to the start and end of the generated .sql file after the scripter has finished?